# Deleting legacy SkyDrive folder with corrupted permissions

Tags: windows, permissions, onedrive

Yep, you're reading this after 2020!

Somehow in my user folder I have a folder titled "Old Onedrive" which is actually `C:/Users/<name>/Skydrive`. I want to delete it because it's 3.5GB of wasted space.

My user account can't delete it, move it, change permissions or anything!
[image: Failure to delete folder]

### The permission entries show:

| Type | Principal | Access |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Allow | Edward (e@gmail.com) | Read & Execute |

The account I am logged in with is the same "Edward (e@gmail.com)" address.

Here is the permissions view.
[image]

I've tried

```
>icacls SkyDrive /reset
SkyDrive: Access is denied.
Successfully processed 0 files; Failed processing 1 files
```

But that didn't work.

Further steps tried: Advanced Security Settings > Owner > Change (From PC\Adminstrator -> Edward (e@gmail.com) which helped me to the answer

Comment: If this stands alone (so deletion does not affect anything else) try Unlocker 1.9.2 (Majorgeeks)

Comment: Who currently is assigned as the owner of the folder? Your local account linked to a Microsoft Account based on the permissions in the screenshot do not have the permissions necessary to delete the folder.  Please [edit] your question to include this necessary information

Comment: Added under: The Permissions entries and I have tried changing the owner, which was successful, regardless of whether I changed it to Administrator (Which my account has those priveledges) or whether I explicitly set the owner to my account name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By changing the owner under Advanced Security settings:
[image: Advanced security settings, change owner dialog]

Then reopening the Properties > Security

[image: Changing object permissions after changing owner]

It is now possible to delete the directory correctly